# Django paginator page return NoneType

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am doing a simple search with Django and using the build in pagination to paginate results and I get this error when I click on next to view the next page results,  int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
I do not know what is causing it, here is the code, q is the query string

```
def result(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET.get('q')
        orders = Order.objects.filter(Q(flat_number=int(q)) | Q(customer_contact=int(q)))
        paginator = Paginator(orders, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        orders = paginator.get_page(page)
        context['orders'] = orders
        return render(request, 'main/results.html',context)
    except Exception as e:
        print('error is ', e)
        return HttpResponse(str(e))
```

Comment: Could you show an example request that you are making, i.e. the full URL that you visit to encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `request.GET.get('q')` it will return None if q is not passes as a parm in the get call.

Changing it to `request.GET['q']` will raise an exception if q is not passed

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mathews, I have change it to request.GET['q'] but it raises and  MultiValueDictKeyError at /result/
'q'

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to work with paginator module, for empty pages etc.

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


def post_list(request): #list items
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all() #.order_by("-timestamp")

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(content__icontains=query)


            ).distinct()

    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "Building stuff with code",
        "page_request_var" : page_request_var
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

try it in the following way

```
def result(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET.get('q')
        orders = Order.objects.filter(Q(flat_number=int(q)) | 
         Q(customer_contact=int(q)))
        paginator = Paginator(orders, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            pots = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            posts = paginador.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginador.page(1)
        context['orders'] = post
        return render(request, 'main/results.html',context)


    except Exception as e:
        print('error is ', e)
        return HttpResponse(str(e))
```